# C2259 : 'ID3D11ShaderResourceView' Cannot instantiate abstract class - DX11

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I'm trying to make a texture handler so that I can load texture file names from a text file and then load the textures and store them into a vector and get them whenever I need to draw.

Problem is, i'm getting the C2259 error which breaks before it can compile and was wondering if anyone could help me out.

TextureManager.h

```
class TextureManager{
private:
    std::vector<ID3D11ShaderResourceView> * textures;
public:
    TextureManager();
    ~TextureManager();
    void TMLoadTexture(ID3D11Device* d);
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView * TMgetTexture(int index);
};
```

TextureManager.cpp - TMLoadTexture / TMGetTexture

```
void TextureManager::TMLoadTexture(ID3D11Device* d)
{
    std::vector<std::string> files;
    files = readFile("textures");

    D3DX11_IMAGE_LOAD_INFO loadInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&loadInfo, sizeof(D3DX11_IMAGE_LOAD_INFO));
    loadInfo.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    loadInfo.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_BC1_UNORM;

for(int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++)
{
    std::wstring stemp = std::wstring(files.at(i).begin(), files.at(i).end());
    LPCWSTR sw = stemp.c_str();

    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* temp;
    D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(d, sw, &loadInfo, NULL, &temp, NULL);
    textures->push_back(*temp);
    delete temp;
}
}

ID3D11ShaderResourceView * TextureManager::TMgetTexture(int index)
{
    return &textures->at(index);
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: If you use vectors as object members and don't know how COM pointers work, you need to learn all of it. I have a feeling you'll leak a lot of memory. This pointers need to be released on `~destruct` or when `&reused`. Plus pointer properties in such scenario makes no sense so you need to learn how C++ objects are created, destroyed and how pointers work. Otherwise... it won't be pretty. So use a COM wrapper for COM pointers to be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ID3D11ShaderResourceView` is an interface, you must use a pointer to access these kind of objects. So:

```
std::vector<ID3D11ShaderResourceView*> * textures;
```

Btw, are you sure that you want to use a `vector`-pointer? I see no reason why a plain `vector<...>` wouldn't be sufficient.

Then when loading the texture, put the pointer in the vector:

```
textures.push_back(temp);
```

And don't delete the texture you just created.

Comment: Thanks, worked with just having it at std::vector<ID3D11ShaderResourceView*> textures;